# Scannin several text files

Tags: python, file, text

I am using python 2.7 and I have a directory with several text files.

Basically the files have the same name and at the end is a counter from `1` to `XX`. I want to search the text files for a specific string and write it to a different file. But I only know how to do that if I put all files to one text file.

I want to scan every text file in my directory and if I find my string I want to put it to e.g. `result.txt` and note there in which file I found it and of course the specific string.

Has someone an idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and wrap it in a `for` loop

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to put in the new file? The whole line that contains the string or only the string? Is it only one string or do you have a list?

Comment: you want to use grep? grep "my string" * > result.txt

Comment: I only want to write the string that I am looking for and the file name of the file where I found it, e.g. file12 my string.
Sorry, I dont know grep.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Do you mean opening every single file by using with open file1 as input...? I could do that if I have a specific amount of files but this can vary.

Comment: @user2834508 I mean use a `for` loop to `open` each file in turn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

files = os.listdir('.')
newfile = 'myfile.txt'
mystring = 'mystring'

found = []
for f in files:
    myfile = open(f, 'r')
    if mystring in myfile.read():
        found.append(f)
    myfile.close()

myfile = open(newfile, 'w')
myfile.write("\n".join(found))
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Sorry fot the late answer but I was very busy.
I am only receiving a file showing all files in my directory but not including the string I am looking for.
The string is definitely there.

Comment: Ok, change `found.append(f)` to `found.append(f+' '+mystring)`